# What is the definition of each of the columns of Prophet's prediction output?

Tags: r, dataframe, prediction, facebook-prophet

When I call predict on a Prophet model the mean prediction is `yhat`, but when I sum across the mean trend and seasonality columns this does not equal the value in `yhat`.

Why do the terms in columns not sum to `yhat`, `yhat_lower` and `yhat_upper`?

Answer (score 0):

Predict function of Prophet using this equation:

```
df2['yhat'] = (
                df2['trend'] * (1 + df2['multiplicative_terms'])
                + df2['additive_terms']
        )
```

Therefore, if you want to manually create `yhat` you need to use those three columns in a given way. If you add any other column, it would be double count because it would be already included in either `additive_terms` or `multiplicative_terms`.